# Search in List within List with Angular Pipe 2

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm having a problem returning a list from passing a parameter. This search I'm trying to filter is from a list that is inside another list. If I pass as field a field from the "outside" list, the return works fine. But I can not filter from the list elements inside. I have a list of employees where I'm trying to filter people out of the skills they have. If I look for the name, for example it works, but I must search for the description of his skills. For example: I pass as parameter "json" and the method returns the employees that have Json skill. Can someone help me please? Thank you.

```
certification: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
gcm: 1
id_employee: 9
manager: "te"
name: "teste t"
project: {id_project: 2, name: "B3", customer: "Ibovespa", 
valueOfProject: 100000, dtBegin: "2018-07-20T03:00:00.000+0000", …}
role: "tete"
salary: 1234
skill: Array(3)
0: {id_skill: 8, descricao: null}
1:
  descricao: "json"
  id_skill: 9
  __proto__: Object
2: {id_skill: 10, descricao: "js"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
if (!items) return [];
return items.filter(it => it[field] == value);
}
```

Comment: Please add the use of the pipe in the html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi args pipe declared with `args: any[]`, like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    return items.filter(it => it[args[0]] == args[1]);
  }
}
```

And use it like this `*ngFor="let skillItem of skill | searchFilter: ['descricao', 'json']"` in any html way you want, something like:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Descricao</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let skillItem of skill | searchFilter: ['descricao', 'json']">
      <td>{{skillItem.id_skill}}</td>
      <td>{{skillItem.descricao}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Created a [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-multi-args) for your to see a complete working example.

Comment: Many thanks for the immense help. All the best to you